# Glanced over her shoulder around the restaurant

Tags: phrases, prepositional-verbs

She glanced over her shoulder around the restaurant.

Does the sentence make sense if she's sitting with her back to the rest of the restaurant? Is it possible to glance over your own shoulder around a place?

Comment: It was obvious to me she had her back to the restaurant when I first read the example. The specifics of her glancing (uneccesary to say she turned her head) over her shoulder needs a second verb as had been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the idea is correct. You need to add a verb before *around the restaurant*, as follows:

> She glanced over her shoulder **and looked** around the restaurant

Comment: Is this possible: She looked over her shoulder around the restaurant.

Comment: Or: She glanced over her should at the restaurant.

Comment: Both examples work as well. Glance or glancing is an all purpose action that can include moving the eyes and head but in the original question 'around' is a second preposition that needs its own verb. In your second example  replacing around with at  it makes it unnecceassay to include looked

Comment: because **at** does not imply the second action of  eye movement. It doesn't mean it does not happen, it just doesn't demand it happened as **around** would.

Comment: You can't glance over your shoulder and very far around, unless you're an owl.